# Apache subdomain redirection failing

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I just bought the domain [vas.im](http://vas.im/), I added a DNS rule for [vas.im](http://vas.im/) and [www.vas.im](http://www.vas.im/), then I tried to get apache2 to redirect the latter to the former. I enabled mod_rewrite, appended `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, which follows, and restarted the apache2 service.

```
ServerName localhost
AccessFileName .htaccess

# Redirect www to non-www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[url]www.vas.im[/url] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [vas.im...] [L,R=301]
```

I must have made some mistake, since the www domain does not redirect. I don't pretend that I understand mod_rewrite, so I'm wondering if someone here knows what the issue is.

Comment: Are those `[url]` tags in the Apache config file?  You might want to remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.vas.im
    #ServerAlias vas.net
    #add aliases if any
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.vas\.im$ [NC]
     RewriteRule ^ http://vas.im/%{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/documentroot
    ServerName vas.im
    ErrorLog logs/your_log_file_name
    CustomLog logs/your_log_file_name common
</VirtualHost>
```

Alternatively, you can change the first virtual host block to:
For this method you have to use [`mod_alias's`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect). So, make sure you have loaded the `mod_alias` module in your `.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.vas.im
    #ServerAlias vas.net
    #add aliases if any
     RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) http://vas.im/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: +1. Do not use mod_rewrite unless it's unavoidable - and certainly not when it's plainly unnecessary.

Comment: It works! Thank you. For some reason the whole internet seems to love the mod_rewrite way of doing this. Oh well.

Comment: @VasiliySharapov: I've noticed the internet at large, almost always, promotes bad practice.  Yes most common copy+pasted config lines work as expected, but usually it's never the proper method.
 BTW, that `RedirectMatch ..` line does not need regex. It should be written as. `Redirect 301 / http://vas.im/`